# How can I invoke code between '<<EOF... EOF' using call system in gfortran?

Tags: bash, gnuplot, gfortran

I want to invoke code between '<<EOF ... EOF' using "call system" to plot with gnuplot (without a file.plt). The following is a general example of the code I wish to use with "call system":

```
gnuplot -persist <<EOF
set title "grafico"
plot "salida.txt"
EOF
```

"salida.txt"

```
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program gnuplot
    implicit none
    character(len=1000) :: command 

    command = "gnuplot -persist <<EOF"//new_line('A')//&
              "set title 'grafico'"//new_line('A')//&
              "plot 'salida.txt'"//new_line('A')//&
              "EOF"

    ! system() is a GNU extension. This is more portable:
    call EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE(command)
end program
```

Note the `//` for string concatenation and the `&` for line continuation.

If you don't mind using GNU extensions, compile with the `-fbackslash` flag and you can write the string like this if you like:

```
    command = "gnuplot -persist <<EOF\n&
              &set title 'grafico'\n&
              &plot 'salida.txt'\n&
              &EOF"
```

Note the `\n` instead of `new_line('A')`. Note also that instead of concatenating strings, this is just a single string. There is a `&` for line continuation like before but there is also a `&` at the beginning of the line if the string is the continuation of the string from the previous line.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think in this way. That lets me write large code with gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

```
gnuplot -persist -e "set title 'grafico'; plot 'salida.txt'"
```

Comment: It doesn't work out of terminal. When I use with call system I get: ```    29 |     call system ("gnuplot -persist -e "set title 'grafico'; plot 'salida.txt'"")
      |                                       1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
do.sh: line 5: ./prog.exe: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like the sequence of closing quotes is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried several different combinations of marks but the error persists. It seems that 'system' can't understand several levels of quotes (like a string into another).